# Using jQuery/jQuery-UI in .NET generated Angular 4 App

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui, asp.net-core, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to use jQuery / jQuery UI in an Angular 4 app generated by Microsoft's SpaTemplate/JavaScript Services (dontnet new angular). This is not using Angular-CLI, and there is no angular-cli.json file.

I've searched for this already, found a few hits on SO for projects generated with the CLI which I can't seem to make work with my project.

I've installed jQuery and jQuery-UI via NPM (jQuery was there already, but I uninstalled and reinstalled it per another SO post answer). This puts them both in the node_modules folder, as well as listing them in the webpack.config.vendor.js, package.json, and package-lock.json files.

webpack.config.vendor.js:

```
entry: {
        vendor: [
            '@angular/animations',
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/forms',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            'jquery',
            'jquery-ui',
            'bootstrap',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'es6-shim',
            'es6-promise',
            'event-source-polyfill',
            'zone.js',
        ]
    },
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
//others removed to keep this short
```

},

package-lock.json (dependencies section)

```
    "jquery": {
  "version": "3.2.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/-/jquery-3.2.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-XE2d5lKvbNCncBVKYxu6ErAVx4c="
},
"jquery-ui": {
  "version": "1.12.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery-ui/-/jquery-ui-1.12.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-vLQEXI3QU5wTS8FIjN0+dop6nlE="
},
```

Now, where I'm lost is just how to use them in the component TS files. I know jQuery is working because this template uses Bootstrap and the hamburger nav works on mobile just fine. Bootstrap is using jQuery to make the drop down animation.

Other posts have said to add this to the component TS file:

```
declare var $:any;
```

Doing just that results in an error when I try to do $('#myElement').datepicker() in the ngOnInit section of the component:

> ```
> vendor.js?v=HQi6Yanr6lb0tcDpEWxOLi8IMea49FFYgwADBy-xMjk:31 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> ```

Another SO post said to do this instead of the declar:

```
import * as $ from 'jQuery';
```

Which then gives me a different error due to it not knowing about jQuery-UI:

> [ts] Property 'datepicker' does not exist on type
>   'JQuery'.

Lastly another answer said this (for Angular2):

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui';
```

However, the jquery import doesn't work because it says jquery has no default export. And I also had to change jqueryui to jquery-ui. Either way, that doesn't work either.

What am I missing? I seem to be finding conflicting answers out there, and they are all related to an app generated with Angular-CLI which I didn't have the luxury of using.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you rebuild your vendor bundles after adding a new reference?
You should execute this command each time you add a new npm package to your vendor config:

```
webpack --config webpack.vendor.config.js
```

Comment: I left out that the app generated by Microsoft has Webpack dev middleware and HMR enabled by default, so I didn't think I would need to. With that said, I gave it a shot with the same result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need the type definition for JQuery . Search for a "@type/jquery" package for JQuery and add it using NPM.

I would avoid using JQuery together with Angular, because in the most cases it doesn't work well. JQuery is working on the DOM and Angular on the virtual DOM, this results in a lot of confusion and errors. It is possible to get it running, but struggled in a lot situation. It's also possible that third-party jQuery libraries are not running properly because of that.

If you need UI components, use some which are designed for Angular:

- https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples
- https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/
- https://angular.io/resources

Comment: Yes, using jQuery-UI definitely wasn't my first choice. However, since Microsoft's generated app already had jQuery itself, I figured it'd be a quick way to get a datepicker. I did try a few modules first, but they didn't seem to work with Server Side Rendering. I didn't try the ng-bootstrap you linked though because it needed Bootstrap 4, and my project is using Bootstrap 3